# Flutter terminate loop when new one starts

Tags: android, flutter, loops, dart

I have a list called songs. I want to perform some action on songs and save them in another list OtherSongs.
Here is an example:

```
Class SongClass{
    List songs = [
      {//song 1},
      {//Song 2},
      ...
    ];
    List otherSongs = [];

    doSomething(){
        otherSongs.clear();
        for(var item in songs){
           // fetch detail of song from internet
           OtherSongs.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

what I want to do is when I call `doSomething()` it starts loop which fetches data from internet. It clearly would take time to complete. but if `doSomething()` is called again before completing, I want previous loop to stop and then start new one.